# Error accessing remote WCF service from Xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, wcf, xamarin.android

I wonder why in same machine localhost:1988/MyService.svc?wsdl responds whereas http://myMachineIp:port/MyService.svc does not.

I did try configuring IIS Express to Accept Remote connections by changing applicationhost file as

```
<bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1988:localhost" />
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1989:MyMachineIP" />
</bindings>
```

and run this command in prompt

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://MyMachineIP:1989/ user=everyone
```

and also setup firewall

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IISExpressMyApplication" dir=in protocol=tcp localport=1989 profile=private remoteip=localsubnet action=allow
```

What else do I need to setup?

I am trying to connect WCF service request from Xamarin Android application running in real device but not in emulator.

Thank you.

Regards
Ishwor

Answer (score 0):

I'm not well-versed in IIS, but found a similar situation that may help you:

[IIS - can't access page by ip address instead of localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029629/iis-cant-access-page-by-ip-address-instead-of-localhost)

Open a command prompt as administrator and type:

```
netsh http add iplisten [MyMachineIP]
```

Where [MyMachineIP] is the IP address of your server.

---

Solution applied:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/30247934/7423333