# SSH Tunneling IIS "Bad Request - Invalid Hostname" When Accessed Through Public IP

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, deployment, ssh-tunnel

I had deployed an ASP.NET project.

It works well in localhost and domain name, but raise an error while accessed through site public IP.

http://wildanmuhlis.com:9000/traders
[image: work well on domain name]

http://45.127.134.46:9000/traders
[image: error when accessed via public IP]

IIS Binding Configuration:
[image]

Notes:
The IIS forwarded to VPS hosting through SSH Tunnel.

Comment: in the IIS binding setting, you need to add the server ip adress which is `45.127.134.46` in your case to the same row of `wildanmuhlis.com:9000`, or you can use the local ip adress, https://www.sherweb.com/blog/cloud-server/how-to-set-up-site-bindings-in-internet-information-services-iis/

Comment: @MobrineHayde, I had assigned the IP as your suggestion. still `Invalid Hostname`

Comment: I think there is a solution for your problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029629/iis-cant-access-page-by-ip-address-instead-of-localhost

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html You use a wrong binding at port 9000, so 400 is expected. If you never know enough about site bindings, please do more experiments to learn the concepts, or let the diagnostics report lead you.

Answer (score 0):

make sure there is no Firewall or ips on your network that block the acess & check the .htacess file & the port forwarding

Comment: well u had to check if your isp dosent block inbound traffic , or maybe your rrouter , check your ports states .